# how to remove user from user@user$ in terminal

Tags: mac, terminal

as topic describes, I want to remove the user@user in my terminal and iterm. What's the best way to solve this.

`root@root-me$ ~`

I just want

`~`

EDIT:
I found out that if I change .zshrc `DEFAULT_USER=myusername` to  my user name, I can achieve this, so I want to know why it needs to be the exact username

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### bash

At the Terminal prompt, type:

```
nano .bashrc
```

Then look for

```
export PS1=" "
```

Between the quotation marks, you can change / add the following lines to customize your prompt:

```
\d – Current date
\t – Current time
\h – Host name
\# – Command number
\u – User name
\W – Current working directory (ie: Desktop/)
\w – Current working directory, full path (ie: /Users/Admin/Desktop)
```

[Source](http://osxdaily.com/2006/12/11/how-to-customize-your-terminal-prompt/)

#### zsh / tcsh

Zsh and tcsh both use `PROMPT`. The color codes are the same, zsh has a slightly different color code escape sequence.

The [tcsh manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/1/tcsh) and [zsh page](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Prompt-Expansion.html) have details on the variables / sequences.

#### fish

Unlike other shells, there is no prompt variable like PS1 or PROMPT. To display your prompt, fish executes a function with the name `fish_prompt`, and its output is used as the prompt.
Multiple lines are OK. Colors can be set via set_color, passing it named ANSI colors, or hex RGB values:

```
> function fish_prompt
        set_color purple
        date "+%m/%d/%y"
        set_color FF0
        echo (pwd) '>'
        set_color normal
  end
02/06/13
/home/tutorial >
```

Comment: this doens't work with zshell does it?

Comment: Edited my answer